# How should I use Realm in React-Native?

Tags: realm, react-native

I've seen a lot of examples of the implementation of realm inside React-Native world but every time I see them I see they export from a root file the instance of the realm database, example:

- realmIndex.js > export new Realm(...configuration)

I was doing that inside one of my projects until I got an issue of memory leak because multiples components that render at the same time, are trying to perform a write into the realm at the same time. So that dispatch a memory leak error on android.

My question is Should I use multiple instances of realm with the same configuration (same path, same schema but different instances), or should I prevent those multiples components of write into realm at the same time?